# Jquery ajax call is not hitting servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a simple ajax call.  No matter what I do, it always executes the error block.  I have a sysout in the doPost that is never hit.  Someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.  Here is my code.

javascript----

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GetBulletAjax",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success");
    },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR+" - "+textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);
    }       
});
```

Java----

```
public class GetBulletAjax extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GetBulletAjax() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("made it to servlet");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
        User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        int userId = user.getId();
        List<Bullet> bullets;

        BulletDAO bulletdao = new BulletDAOImpl();
        try {
            bullets = bulletdao.findBulletsByUser(userId);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(bullets);
            System.out.println(json);
            out.println(json);
            out.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}
```

web.xml----

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetBulletAjax</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bulletAjax.GetBulletAjax</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetBulletAjax</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/GetBulletAjax</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting back?  What is `textStatus` and `errorThrown`?

Comment: the alert says "[object Object] - error - Not Found"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's the URL for your client?  Your URL is going to be relative -- so if your page's URL is `<server>/foo/bar.html`, your ajax request is going to go to `<server>/foo/GetBulletAjax`.  But your servlet definition is `<server>/GetBulletAjax`.

Change your `url` in your ajax request to `/GetBulletAjax`.  You need the leading forward slash to tell the browser the resource is located off the root of the site.

Comment: I tried this previously, and again when you suggested it.  It did not work.  I get the same error.

Comment: My mistake!!! you are completely correct!  The page that is sending this request was one directory down from my context root.  I had to change it to ../GetBulletAjax and everything worked great.  Thank you for your time. +1

Comment: No problem - glad I could help.  Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner with your earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

in Jquery documentation

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

seems that you miss the type attribute which needs to be POST. default is GET as mentioned by documentation. You dont have a doGet in your servlet to support that.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "GetBulletAjax",
   dataType: 'json',
   type:POST,
   success: function(data) {
      alert("success");
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(jqXHR+" - "+textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);
   }       
});
```

Comment: His `doGet` forwards the request and response variables to `doPost`.  He has a `doGet` in his code.

Comment: Yes, David is correct.  I tried it just to be sure.  That is not the issue.